# IsValid not validating AreaPath and IterationPath

Tags: tfs

I have been trying to create a user story in TFS 2012 programatically. After passing some of the fields including AreaPath and IterationPath to the WorkItem object and trying to create, on calling IsValid before save, its throwing back the AQreaPath and IterationPath as invalid data. I have read an user story programatically which lies on the same path and iteration, and have used the same value programatically, but it doesn't work out on save. Please help. I have just started on TFS programming and have very little knowledge yet, so might be missing some basic thing.

*The value I have passed while saving are something like this
AreaPath: HCSInquiry\HandsOn
IterationPath: HCSInquiry

Comment: Do you have permission to save data to these paths? Are you saving the work item in the same team project you're reading the values from?

Comment: yes, its the same path where I am reading and trying to save to

Comment: @s10, be sure that the AreaPath and IterationPath is correct. An easy way is just create one work item in VSIDE and assign the Area and Iteration, and copy the Area and Iteration path to use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfscollectionURL"));
        WorkItemStore wis = tfctc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        WorkItemType wiType = wis.Projects["ProjectName"].WorkItemTypes["User Story"];
        WorkItem newWI = new WorkItem(wiType);
        newWI.Title = "Title_2";
        newWI.AreaPath = "HCSInquiry\\HandsOn";
        newWI.IterationPath = "HCSInquiry";
        newWI.Save();
```